# $.get not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

This displays 1 no matter what I echo in getbillno.php - also why I'm not showing that part anymore.
Nothing would change unless I change bill into a string
or put tbl (just to see what happens) in its place, so I figured the problem is not
in getbillno.php but with this part right here. I'm very
much new to jQuery and I really can't see what's wrong
with this.

This works perfectly with Chrome, FF, and in Safari. I have other functions with jQuery in the same page and those work fine in any browser including IE(9). It's just with this one that I'm having problems.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getbillno(tbl){

$.get("getbillno.php?tbl="+ tbl, function(bill){
$("#billno").val(bill); });
}   
</script>
```

I'm trying to make this work with IE(9) because it's the only browser
that lets me have the Print options I want.

Comment: When you say "returns 1", do you mean the element identified by "#billno" gets set to 1? Is it an input element, or...?

Comment: It displays 1 in the text field. Even when I erase everything in getbillno.php.

Comment: So IE must be closed first after first change of the display instead of just hitting refresh after changing parts of the script . . not good