# Is there a way to call php with an event other than $.get?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, events

EDIT : Found the solution to my problem below. See it here -> [IE must close for event with jQuery to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656493/ie-must-close-for-event-with-jquery-to-work)

I've been asking around, trying to figure this one out. If there are any other way to do a mySql query in PHP by an event .. other than $.get.

I've previously posted this one other problem just in case somebody could help out ->
[$.get not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633511/get-not-working-in-ie)

Now I'm trying to find a way around the problem I previously posted cause if $.get is not going to happen in IE for me then there has to be another way with this. Maybe not with jQuery

Comment: Your other question is equally unclear.  `$.get` should work fine in all browsers, but we would need more details to diagnose your particular issue.  The only replacement is going to be another library or do the `XmlHTTPRequest` yourself, which is a royal pain.

Comment: how is the fact that you're using php relevant?

Comment: About my other question @mellamokb, in IE the script that I'd shown would always return a display of 1 regardless of what I echo on the other page and I even tried removing the whole content -  the display would always be 1. I'd called that function getbillno(tbl) through another function that I'd put in my previous post.

Comment: @miki I'm looking for a way to call a PHP script by an event .. and if I can't figure out a way to make my program work in IE with $.get I would need other solutions

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could try the longhand syntax (as $.get is a shorthand alias of $.ajax)

```
function getbillinfo(tbl) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getbillno.php",
        data: "tbl=" + tbl,
        success: function(bill){
            $("#billno").val(bill); });
        }
    });
}
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**Edit:** with regard to your problems with IE, there could be a couple of reasons

Possibility One

> IE caches the results of Ajax calls to the same resource even if you
>   tell it not to in your HTTP headers. So if you make a request to
>   getbillinof.php?tbl=table over and over again, IE will make the
>   request once and then stop making it in the future and simply return
>   the result of the first request. To circumvent this you can call getbillinof.php?tbl=table&random_string_here
>
> It may also be worth setting cache: false in the ajax() options and having a look into the isModified option.

Possibility Two

> A [Race Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) is causing the IE render action to run before
>   any data was returned. This however is unlikely as the success()
>   function is only supposed to run once the data has been received. A
>   race condition becomes far more likely if you're doing something like

```
function getbillinfo(tbl) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getbillno.php",
        data: "tbl=" + tbl,
        success: function(bill){
            var mydata = bill;
        }
    });

    $("#billno").val(mydata);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ben, IE is still not cooperating. But I'm not going to stop experimenting for other ways but first I'll have to find out what the real problem is.

Comment: found out I have to close the browser for IE to let jQuery change the display/content of the page. So that's what but why ..

Comment: Added to my answer in an attempt to answer your question about IE