# IE must close for event with jQuery to work

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, events

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getbillno(tbl){

    $.get("getbillno.php?tbl="+ tbl, function(bill){
    $("#billno").val(bill); });
    } 
    </script>
```

QUICK Overview : function getbillno(tbl) returns a display of 1 as a default (ELSE echo "1").

PROBLEM : In IE no matter what I display even when the page is a blank, it would always display 1.

Instead of hitting refresh, I tried closing IE(9) and it did display the right value. I changed the value in my code again then refreshed IE, it would display the one before that - it's the value after I reopened IE.

Question : Is there a setting or whatever it is that I have to change or configure in IE(9)?

I've been asking questions around the internet before I found out what closing the browser would do. I thought it had something to do with my program, or maybe it does - so here are a few links. Just as background because I'm not sure if seeing my other questions would change much.

[1] [$.get not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633511/get-not-working-in-ie)
[2] [Is there a way to call php with an event other than $.get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655588/is-there-a-way-to-call-php-with-an-event-other-than-get)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE caches get requests

You can disable this with [cache: false](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#options) parameter in jquery get

> Default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp' If set to
>   false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser.
>   Setting cache to false also appends a query string parameter,
>   "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL.

Comment: Wow. This did it I can't thank you enough @Hasan. I can finally move on to other things.

Comment: @esandrkwn You might want to accept and upvote the answer in that case.

Comment: I'd get back to this when I earn enough rep (I only have 11) and I'd post a link of this in my previous posts for others to see